# Dynamic evaluation of functions in JS (is this safe?)

Tags: javascript, security

I have a website in which all the pages are processed through an index.php that includes different PHP files depending on the requested URL (this is done through mod_rewrite).

I'm using the following method to execute specific functions at page load:

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
readyFns = Array();
</script>

<?php
// Do some stuff here, and pull the name of the PHP page to include from the DB
include $pageToInclude
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    commonFunctionToApplyToAllThePages();
    otherCommonFunction();

    // page-specific functions
    for (i=0; i<readyFns.length; i++)
    {
    if (typeof(window[readyFns[i]]) == "function")
        window[readyFns[i]]();
    }    
</script>
```

**includedPage.php**

```
<?php
// Generate page
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
readyFns.push("someFunction");
readyFns.push("someOtherFunction");
</script>
```

I quite like this approach because I just have to set readyFns at the end of this page and everything else will be nicely controlled by `index.php`.
My questions is: is this safe? Could it be sensitive to someone generating a link that arbitrarily sets `readyFns` to point to some malicious code and then links to my site? 
How would I prevent that?

thanks
nico

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting.  In principle, it's probably ok, but you're right to be a little concerned.  This is just compiling a list of keys to lookup as functions on an object, and execute, so it's not really a security problem in that respect.  But, you are essentially providing access to all globals like that.  You'd probably be better off making a global object besides `window` to store your functions on, like so:

```
var funcs = {};
funcs.someFunction = function() {/*blah*/};
funcs.someOther = function() {/*blah*/};
```

and then your `readyFuncs` thing would loop over `funcs` instead of `window`.  I don't think there'd be anything to worry about past that.

Of course, there are other things with your approach that could be improved, but I think it's ok as-is if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but wouldn't that just move the problem? I mean, one could define a malicious function in `functs` instead of the main scope, no? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's technically possible, but it's not something to worry about.  I moved it out of window so you don't give access to built-ins like `setTimeout` or `alert`.